# Memory Optimization with Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, memory, multiprocessing

Issue is we have a service which does json flattening and then converts the flattened json to parquet. All this is done using pandas dataframes. but the memory utilization is very high, and after a few hundred files the ECS task is crashing due to OOM issue.

After doing memory profiling we found that the python is not releasing unused memory, and it is getting occupied and once all the memory is occupied, task is getting killed.

No to resolve this issues, after doing a bit research, did a some changes to run the flattening and parquet conversion process it a separate subprocess using python Multiprocessing, below is the code snippet.

```
for file_index, s3_json_file_key in enumerate(s3_json_file_keys):       
   process = Process(self.process_file, (s3_json_file_key,))
   process.start()
   process.join()
```

This is working perfectly fine, but now the issue I am getting is, after processing a few thousand files, the process is just getting hanged and it not processing any files anymore and there are no errors, just nothing happening.

I am thinking it is because we are create a new process for each file and which is create thousands of processes. To resolved this I tried using a pool but that is not working, again seeing same memory usage.

Can someone suggest me anything.

Comment: have you tried to research the problem with [memory-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/)?

Comment: Calling `process.close()` may help.

Comment: Have you checked that if you process one file at a time in the main process instead of using multiprocessing, the memory usage will not increase?

Comment: yes i did the memory profiling using memory-profiler package.

Comment: we did the file processing in main process sequentially one file at a time, with that only the memory was getting occupied and was not releasing, and ecs task was getting killed due to OOM after around 400 files. and the ecs task is running with 2CPU and 4GB Memory.